# DNS Replication & Forwarders

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, domain-controller, replication

I don't even know how to begin asking this question, but hopefully someone will understand as I'm a noob when it comes to DNS especially.

Basically I'm sitting with a Windows 2008 R2 dc with AD,DNS. This domain controller has been our primary Domain since I got here(let's call her DC1). There was another 2008 dc with AD/DNS as well by someone(probably the same person that did DC1), lets call him DC2. I've setup a 2016 DC myself recently, DC3.

The forwarders for DC1 is setup for google dns (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4), but looking at DC2 and DC3 the forwarding IP points to my router gateway IP. Is this normal? I would've thought since DNS replicated from DC1 this would've been the same setting for all 3 DC's, i.e. google dns (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4).

Please advise. I'm looking forward to hear from you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forwarders are a configuration setting unique to each DNS server. Forwarders do not replicate between DNS servers the way DNS zones do. If you want your DNS servers to use the same Forwarders you'll have to configure each of them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the fast respone joe, will do just that.

Comment: Glad to help...